# Nested Master Pages and Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

I created a nested master page. The parent master page A inherits from System.Web.UI.MasterPage. The child master page B inherits from A.

I then created a web content page C which uses master page B, and inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.

From the web content page C I am able to access variables and methods from within both master pages. However the problem lies in accessing the parent master page variables and methods.

The problem is that a NullReferenceException is being raised. Variables and methods are not being initialised.

What is a possible solution?

```
public partial class ParentMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    internal Button btn_Parent
    {
    get { return btn; }
    }
}

public partial class ChildMasterPage : ParentMasterPage
{
    internal Button btn_Child
    {
        get { return btn; }
    }
}

public partial class WebContentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Button tempA = Master.btn_Child; //WORKS
        Button tempB = Master.btn_Parent; //NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Comment: Try providing a more complete question with source code, where the error is thrown, ...

Answer (score 1):

A nested master page does not *inherit* it's parent master page's type. Instead it *composes* itself such that the `NestedMasterType.Master` property is an instance of the parent master page. The `NestedMasterType` type still inherits from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`.

So this is right:

```cs
public partial class ChildMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

This is wrong:

```
public partial class ChildMasterPage : ParentMasterPage
```

You would then access the (parent) Master of the (child) Master of a Page (that uses the child master) like this:

```
Button tempA = ((ChildMasterPage)this.Master).btn_Child; 
Button tempB = ((ParentMasterPage)this.Master.Master).btn_Parent;
```

Note: This answer assumes that you mean that `ChildMasterPage` is a nested master page, that uses a `Master` directive similar to the below:

```
<%@ Master MasterPageFile="~/ParentMasterPage.Master" Inherits="ChildMasterPage"...
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only has a reference to it's *immediate* master and it's variables, you would have to traverse up the object graph to the main master page i.e.

```
var parentMaster = (ParentMasterPage)Page.Master.Master;
parentMaster.SomeProperty = ...;
```

Alternatively, you could bridge the gap between the 2 by implementing the same property in your `ChildMasterPage` i.e.

```
internal Button btn_Parent
{
    get { return ((ParentMasterPage)Master).btn_Parent; }
}
```

This would mean the code you currently have would work, however, it sort of defeats the purpose of having a main master page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it seems to work out. However I am intending to make the code more scalable. Isn't there a way to access the same propery for all the required methods and variables of both master pages?

Comment: I am able to access the properties, however they are not being initialised. Is there a way to initialise them?

Comment: @JEPAAB Not that I know if, also this sort of code shouldn't have any sort of negative performance impact. *I am able to access the properties, however they are not being initialised* - the example you shows returns a `btn` field, make sure you are initialising that *somewhere* in your master page.